# Ошибка с build gradle (несовместимость версии)

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, build

Любительски кодю на андроид студио с движком LibGDX. Все было хорошо, пока в один день я не попробовал построить апк и не получил ошибку несовместимости build gradle, после чего я ребилднул проект и вся прога перестала работать. При запуске пишется "Unfortunatly *название приложения* has stopped."Прикладываю код, может ошибка и в нем, но я склоняюсь к ошибке в грэдле. Помогите разобраться.

```
package com.hobogames.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PixmapPacker;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

import sun.applet.Main;


public class Lobby extends ApplicationAdapter {



    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture backgroundimg;
    Texture start_buttonimg;
    Texture lobby_text1;
    Texture lobby_text2;
    Texture settingsimg;
    Texture square4menuimg;
    Texture back_buttonimg;
    Texture square4volumeimg;
    Texture volume_upimg;
    Texture volume_offimg;
    Texture list1_questionimg;
    Texture list1_aswer1img;
    Texture list1_answer2img;
    Texture list1_answer3img;

    Vector3 touchPos;

    Rectangle settings;
    Rectangle square4menu;
    Rectangle start_button;
    Rectangle list1_question;
    Rectangle list1_answer1;
    Rectangle list1_answer2;
    Rectangle list1_answer3;

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;

    Music lobby_theme;
    Music game_theme;
    Sound on_clicked;

    public boolean inlobby = true;
    public boolean green_theme = true;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    boolean getting_smaller = false;
    public boolean getting_bigger = true;
    public boolean settings_opened = false;
    public boolean game_process = false;
    public boolean perehod = false;
    public int volumr_up = 0;
    public int list = 0;

    private BitmapFont backfont;
    private BitmapFont backfont2;



    @Override
    public void create ()  {


        backfont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("newarial128.fnt"));
        backfont.getData().setScale(0.35f);
        touchPos = new Vector3();


        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        backgroundimg = new Texture("background.png");
        start_buttonimg = new Texture("start_button.png");
        lobby_text1 = new Texture("lobby_text1.png");
        lobby_text2 = new Texture ("lobby_text2.png");
        settingsimg = new Texture("settings.png");
        square4menuimg = new Texture("square4menu2.png");
        back_buttonimg = new Texture("back_button.png");
        square4volumeimg = new Texture("square4volume.png");
        volume_offimg = new Texture("volume_off.png");
        volume_upimg = new Texture("volume_up.png");
        list1_questionimg = new Texture("list1_question.png");
        list1_aswer1img = new Texture ("list1_answer1.png");
        list1_answer2img = new Texture("list1_answer2.png");
        list1_answer3img = new Texture("list1_answer3.png");

        lobby_theme = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("lobby_theme.mp3"));
        game_theme = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("game_theme.mp3"));
        on_clicked = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("on_clicked2 (online-audio-converter.com).mp3"));
        lobby_theme.setLooping(true);
        game_theme.setLooping(true);

        lobby_theme.setVolume(0.5f);
        game_theme.setVolume(0.75f);

        if (inlobby){lobby_theme.play();}


        start_button = new Rectangle();
        square4menu = new Rectangle();
        settings = new Rectangle();
        list1_question = new Rectangle();
        list1_answer1 = new Rectangle();
        list1_answer2 = new Rectangle();
        list1_answer3 = new Rectangle();


        square4menu.width = 660;
        square4menu.height = 720-150;
        square4menu.x = 720/2 - square4menu.width/2;
        square4menu.y = 1280/2 - square4menu.height/2 - 200;

        settings.width = 125;
        settings.height = 125;
        settings.x = 720 - settings.width - 15;
        settings.y = 0 + 15;

        start_button.width = 325;
        start_button.height = 325;
        start_button.x = 720/2 - start_button.width/2;
        start_button.y = 1280/2-300 + 50 - start_button.height/2;


        list1_question.height = 200;
        list1_question.width = 600;
        list1_question.x = 20;
        list1_question.y = 1280 - list1_question.height - 40;

        list1_answer1. height = 200;
        list1_answer1.width = 600 ;
        list1_answer1.x =720- list1_answer1.width  - 20 ;
        list1_answer1.y =1280 - 2*list1_question.height - 250;

        list1_answer2.height = 200;
        list1_answer2.width = 600;
        list1_answer2.x = list1_answer1.x;
        list1_answer2.y = list1_answer1.y - list1_answer2.height - 40;

        list1_answer3.height = 200;
        list1_answer3.width = 600;
        list1_answer3.x = list1_answer2.x;
        list1_answer3.y = list1_answer2.y - list1_answer3.height - 40;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);




    }

    private void perehod_from_list1 () {

        list1_answer1.x += 500* Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        list1_answer3.x += 500* Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        list1_question.x -= 500*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        list1_answer2.x -= 500*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    }

    private void getting_bigger () {

        if (getting_bigger) {
            start_button.width += 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            start_button.height += 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if (start_button.height > 500){getting_bigger = false; getting_smaller = true;}
            }

    }
    private void getting_smaller () {
        if (getting_smaller) {
        start_button.width -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        start_button.height -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (start_button.height < 350) {getting_smaller = false;   getting_bigger = true;}
    }
    }
    public static void waiting (int n){
        long t0, t1;
        t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        do{
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        while (t1 - t0 < n);
    }

    private void start_button_animation() {

        if (getting_bigger){getting_bigger();}

        if (getting_smaller){getting_smaller();}

            }



    @Override
    public void render () {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();


        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();


        batch.draw(backgroundimg, 0, 0);
        if (inlobby){batch.draw(start_buttonimg, start_button.x, start_button.y, start_button.width, start_button.height);
        batch.draw(lobby_text1, 720/2 - 700/2 , 1280-200 - 250/2, 700, 250 );
        batch.draw(lobby_text2, 720/2 - 700/2 + 50 , 1280-250 - 250/2*2, 700-250, 250 );}



        if (game_process){

            if (list == 1) {
                batch.draw(list1_questionimg, list1_question.x, list1_question.y, list1_question.width, list1_question.height);
                batch.draw(list1_aswer1img, list1_answer1.x, list1_answer1.y, list1_answer1.width, list1_answer1.height);
                batch.draw(list1_answer2img, list1_answer2.x, list1_answer2.y, list1_answer2.width, list1_answer2.height);
                batch.draw(list1_answer3img, list1_answer3.x, list1_answer3.y, list1_answer3.width, list1_answer3.height);

            }

        }





        if (volumr_up % 2 == 0) {
            batch.draw(volume_upimg, settings.x, settings.y, settings.width, settings.height);
            if (inlobby){lobby_theme.play();}; if (game_process) {game_theme.play();}
        }
        if (volumr_up % 2 == 1) {
            batch.draw(volume_offimg, settings.x, settings.y, settings.width, settings.height);
            lobby_theme.pause(); if (game_process) {game_theme.pause();}
        }

        if (game_process) {lobby_theme.pause();}

        batch.end();

        if (perehod) {perehod_from_list1();}
        start_button.x = 720/2 - start_button.width/2;
        start_button.y = 1280/2-300 + 50 - start_button.height/2;

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPos);
            if ((touchPos.x > settings.x) & (touchPos.y < settings.height) ) {
                volumr_up++; }

            if ( (touchPos.x > start_button.x) & (touchPos.x < start_button.x+start_button.width) &
                    (touchPos.y > start_button.y) & (touchPos.y < start_button.y + start_button.height)){

                inlobby = false;
                game_process = true;
                list = 1;

                }
                if (game_process) {



                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                        if ( (touchPos.x > list1_answer1.x) & (touchPos.x < list1_answer1.x + list1_answer1.width)
                        & (touchPos.y > list1_answer1.y) & (touchPos.y < list1_answer1.y + list1_answer1.height) )
                {if (volumr_up % 2 == 0)on_clicked.play(); perehod = true;}
                    if ( (touchPos.x > list1_answer2.x) & (touchPos.x < list1_answer2.x + list1_answer2.width)
                            & (touchPos.y > list1_answer2.y) & (touchPos.y < list1_answer2.y + list1_answer2.height) )
                    {if (volumr_up % 2 == 0)on_clicked.play();perehod = true;}
                    if ( (touchPos.x > list1_answer3.x) & (touchPos.x < list1_answer3.x + list1_answer3.width)
                            & (touchPos.y > list1_answer3.y) & (touchPos.y < list1_answer3.y + list1_answer3.height) )
                    {if (volumr_up % 2 == 0)on_clicked.play();perehod = true;}
                    }







                }

        }


        if (inlobby){start_button_animation();}




    }



    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        backgroundimg.dispose();
        start_buttonimg.dispose();
        lobby_theme.dispose();
        game_theme.dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: Вам стоит приложить ЛОГ, так же код из build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю Вы обновили версию Gradle до 4-ки, но библиотека LIBGDX не совместима с этой версией, поэтому происходит эта ошибка.

Попробуйте в конфигурационных файлах Gradle понизить версию до: `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`, либо до 3.0.1.

А так же указать дистрибутив не 4-ой версии, а ниже: `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`
Надеюсь Вам это поможет.